# Mongodb suggests I create collection.sessions Index?

Tags: mongodb

Mongodb Performance Advisor is suggesting I create an index for my collection called CareerTest. See image below. Can someone explain to me what this is suggesting / referring to?

```
careertest.sessions
expires: 1

Existing Indexes In This Collection (1)
_id: 1
SINGLE
```

Sample Query #1

```
REMOVE
expires: Object
$lt: Mon Oct 18 2021 11:14am
```

[image]

Comment: Indexes are sorted data structures.  A sorted data structure is easier and faster to find or search upon compared to an unordered data structure.  For this reason, most databases provide such features.  You have queries against a collection called `careertest.sessions` where an index is missing.  These queries would benefit from an index.  The Performance Advisor has identified the proper index shape and is recommending it be created to improve performance.  It is saying to create an index on field `expires` in an ascending order.

Comment: The original `_id` index already exists.  If you accept the recommendation you will then have 2 indexes, one on `_id` and another on `expires`.  The expectation is that future queries against this collection having the `expires` field as either a filter predicate or a sort predicate will gain performance benefits by this new index.

Comment: If you review the GUI tab `Profiler` you should see operations that include queries to the collection `careertest.sessions`.  These operations will appear in a graph as a colored dot.  Any colored dots on the `Profiler` tab represent slow operations and are a candidate for performance improvements.

Comment: This is crazy helpful thanks so much Barry! Would sessions be something express created per chance? I have not made a collection called sessions.

Comment: Curious - what version of MongoDB are you running?

Comment: MongoDB version 3.5.9

Comment: Hmmm.  3.5.9 was not a production release.  Mongo released 3.4 then released 3.6.  Perhaps you are referring to the NodeJS driver version?

Comment: Assuming you are using Ops Manager, (or Atlas) you can see the version of the databases on the cluster view under the label 'Version'...

Comment: if you query `careertest.sessions` (either via mongoshell or via GUI data explorer) what do you see?  Are the fields consistent with your business or does the data points look like mongo metadata?